# Problems with creating controls dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I'm having some issues with creating labels dynamically. I'm trying to create a 15x15 grid with an "X" label per cell, and the code is sort of working, it creates the first label but not the others, I've tried debugging the code with breakpoints and it's calling the `Controls.Add` the right amount of times but it's only creating one label. Here's the code:

```
class PlayingGrid
{
    const int MAX_CELLS = 15;
    Cell[,] grids = new Cell[MAX_CELLS, MAX_CELLS];

    public PlayingGrid()
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < MAX_CELLS; y++)
        {
            int yPoint = y * 12;

            for (int x = 1; x < MAX_CELLS; x++)
            {
                int xPoint = x * 12;
                grids[y, x] = new Cell(new Point(xPoint, yPoint));
            }
        }
    }
}
class Cell
{
    #region Fields & Properties
    public Letter Letter;
    public Point Point;
    public static GameForm refForm;
    #endregion

    //Default constructor will create an empty cell
    public Cell(Point point)
    {
        Letter = new Letter(LatinAlphabet.Empty);
        this.Point = point;           
        refForm.Invoke(new Action(()=> refForm.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "X", Location = point })));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they're not being created on top of each other, and it's just the location code that's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set label AutoSize property to true:

```
new Label() {AutoSize =true, Text = "X", Location = point }
```

Because with default size all label hided in below of last label.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Would anyone just mind explaining what that property actually does? :) I'm still learning so.

Comment: From MSDN: `AutoSize` property Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control is automatically resized to display its entire contents.` if you create a `Label` in Designer it is set to `true` by default, but if you are creating label at runtimeit is set to `false` bydefault so syou need to explicitly make it to `true`